# Using Powershell to recursively output folder contents to separate .txt files

Tags: windows, powershell, directory, command

I'm attempting to use Powershell to output my folder contents to a text file recursively, sorted by LastWriteTime.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
ProjectData
  Proj1
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
  Proj2
    image1.jpg
    file1.txt
```

I'm attempting to get an output that looks like this:

```
Proj1.txt (contents of txt file to include file1.txt, file2.txt)
Proj2.txt (contents of txt file to include image1.jpg, file1.txt)
```

I've tried the following, which outputs the entire directory listing into a single txt file. I'm not sure it's possible to do what I want with Powershell.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\hmd\Desktop\PSTest' | Sort-Object LastWriteTime >> 'C:\Users\hmd\Desktop\PSTest\output.txt'
```

As well, this produces similar results:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse C:\Users\hmd\Desktop\PSTest | ForEach-Object { $_.Name } > C:\Users\hmd\PSTest\output.txt
```

I think what needs to happen is, in the ForEach loop, it needs to recursively look into each directly and output the txt file. I'm unclear on how to approach this and would appreciate any suggestions/tips.

Comment: By contents of the files what do you mean?

Comment: Where should the files be written to? And what if there are conflicting folder names, eg `Proj1` and `Proj2` both having a `bin` or `lib` folder for example?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Sorry, I meant the filename. I'd like to compile a list of all filenames, sorted by LastWriteTime as separate .txt files. The output .txt filename should be the name of the folder.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The files can be written to the root directory of the project folder (or anywhere, really). There are no duplicated folder names. 

Proj1.txt should contain all subfolder and filenames within that folder. 

Proj2.txt should also contain all subfolder and filenames within it.

For this example, the output should have 2 text files called Proj1.txt and Proj2.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly you need to first look for all folders 1 level deep then get all files for each folder:

```
# look for all directories 1 level deep
Get-ChildItem ProjectData -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    # construct the destination path for this folder
    $dest = Join-Path 'C:\Users\hmd\Desktop\PSTest' -ChildPath "$($_.Name).txt"
    # get all files `Name` from this directory (recursively)
    ($_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime).Name |
        # store the files in a txt file using the parent folder name
        Set-Content $dest
}
```

If you want all files in a single line joined by a delimiter you can use `-join`:

```
($_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime).Name -join ','
```

Comment: Wow! It works! Unbelievable. Thank you also for including the comments for each process. I have one follow-up question. Why is it that even though Sort-Object is used, the outputted txt file fails to actually include the last modified date? In the example in the question, the resulting txt file includes the last modified date in the txt file.

Comment: @Stangn99 that's because we're expanding the `.Name` property of each object when doing `(....).Name`. If you want to keep the `Name` and the `LastWriteTime` you could do `$_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime` instead. At which point I would recommend you to export your output using `Export-Csv` instead of `Set-Content` :)

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the pointer. I'll look into Export-CSV, and now that I think about it, it makes more sense anyway to ouput to a CSV instead of TXT for what I plan to do with the data.